# Creating a editable master cost list spreadsheet that is referenced by multiple google spreadsheets for costing recipes

Tags: java, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a centralised list of ingredients that are brought into a warehouse. I know the Name, Volume & Cost of each of those ingredients and have detailed them in a master spreadsheet that will be updated with new ingredients and amended prices as time goes on.

[image: Sample of the Master cost spreadsheet]

I also have a bunch of recipes spreadsheets that use those ingredients. What I'd like to do is have those recipes spreadsheets reference the master spreadsheet to pull the cost value in the cell and volume value in the adjacent cell when the name of the ingredient is mentioned in plain English and then have those values updated when the master spreadsheet is amended.

```html
function dataLookUp(item) {
    var item = item.toLowerCase() // convert to lower case 
        .trim()                     // remove spaces at the start and at end
        .replace(/ +/g, ' ');       // replaces double spaces with single spaces
    
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Master Cost ID").getSheetByName("Cost");
      var sheets = ss.getsheets();
      var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

    function get_value(item) {
       
        var texts = ['GNS@60'];
        if (texts.includes(item))      return 0.64;
    }
    function get_volume(item) {
       
        var texts = ['GNS@60'];
        if (texts.includes(item))      return 1000; //in adjacent cell
    }
    }
```

I have tried a few methods and I'm struggling to get this off the ground. I'm trying to express what I want to do in garbage code, apologies if my code doesn't make sense. I don't particularly want to use `IF` because then every time I add a new ingredient, I'll have to change the script with hundreds of entries.
I'm at a bit of a loss where to go.

**EDIT -**
As requested, a [sample spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vLnmpBCIDD5aB1zBPlw7HTq69RAr2QpZuN83VJWtAQ4/edit#gid=1427038959)
Thanks for helping out with this code:

```html
/**
 * This fuction determines whether the ingredient is in the database & returns it's price point and breaks
 * @constructor
 * @customfunction
 *  */ 

function getCost(itemname){
  const ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ssh = ss1.getSheetByName('Cost');
  let tf = ssh.getRange('A1:A'+ ssh.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(itemname).findNext();
  return ssh.getRange(tf.getRow(),3).getValue();
}
function getVol(itemname){
  const ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ssh = ss1.getSheetByName('Cost');
  let tf = ssh.getRange('A1:A'+ ssh.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(itemname).findNext();
  return ssh.getRange(tf.getRow(),2).getValue();
}
```

This works great for a cost sheet that is in the same spreadsheet, but what I'm wanting to achieve is scraping values from an external spreadsheet (as in a different file) that is updated separately. This way if 20 recipes use the same ingredient and the price changes, I can just update the master cost spreadsheet instead of individually changing each file.
I'm running into a problem when trying to point the script towards an external spreadsheet via `SpreadsheetApp.openById` which pings an error:

> Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

I've read that .openById doesn't work anymore for what I'm trying to do. Is there another method to do this?

**EDIT 2**

I've added the Google Sheets API through services and I have created a custom menu item to trigger the permissions check needed to access the external spreadsheet, although it doesn't ping a permissions check and I'm still getting the same error as the previous edit. See what I've added:

```html
`/**
 * This function calls the database through a custom menu to give permission
 */

function onOpen() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Database')
  .addItem('Access', 'accessDB')
  .addToUi();
}
function accessDB() {
  SpreadsheetApp.openById('Database ID');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Database now active!');
}`
```

Not quite sure what's going wrong here.

Comment: Could you share an example Spreadsheet? That way the community will be able to help you out in a better way, please try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue with your current code.

Comment: @GabrielCarballo - I must have missed that. Amended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Return item cost

```
function getCost(itemname){
  const ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ssh = ss1.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  let tf = sh.createTextFinder(itemname).findNext();
  return ssh.getRange(tf.getRow(),3).getValue();
}
```

or

```
function getCost(itemname){
  const ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ssh = ss1.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  let tf = sh.getRange('A1:A'+ ssh.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(itemname).findNext();
  return ssh.getRange(tf.getRow(),3).getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

Since now you are getting a permission error when opening the external script you could try the following:

- Try adding the specific scopes in the appscript.json file manifest, to do this follow this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes).
- If the above still throws the same message find your project and remove all access from your [account settings](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions), once done try giving permissions to the script again when running the code.

Comment: Hey @Gabriel , I've tried both of these things and I'm still getting errors. There wasn't a prompt to ask for permissions when running the script after I revoked the permissions. I have another script that runs on this file that adds a new, renamed tab and that asked for permission. I added this line to the manifest:
`"oauthScopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
  ],`

Comment: Are you getting the same error or a different error is now showing up?

Comment: It's the same error:
`Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`

Comment: Have you tried adding the Google Sheets API in the services option? I was as well checking that using custom functions on a spreadsheet directly won't allow you to use the SpreadsheetApp.openById() method but you could create a custom menu as stated in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services).

Comment: I've added the Google Sheets API in the services and I have also created a menu item through a custom menu that should ping up a permissions check, but doesn't. I'm still getting the same error message as before. 
See the update for the added code.